# SQL To Text Box

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, vba

Simple enough, I'm trying to take information out of a Column in an SQL Database where the Members_ID is equal to the integer the users inputs to a Textbox.

- SendFromID.Text is the textbox containing the Members_ID
- Current_Points is the textbox I want to hold/show the SQL Column info
- U_G_Studio is the SQL Column holding the data

Only 1 row can match the Members_ID as it's a Primary Key.

This is as far as I've managed to get with my code; after this I just get lost. If you could provide an example in code I'd really appreciate it.

```
stcon = "CONNECTION STRING;"
        con = New SqlConnection(stcon)

        con.Open()

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT U_G_Studio FROM PersonsA WHERE Members_ID ='" & SendFromID.Text & "'", con)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
```

{EDIT 1}

Just want to clarify, I need to DOWNLOAD the data **from** the SQL Column **into** the texbox.

Comment: Remove quote across the `SendFromID.Text`. Also use parameters.

Comment: This is so prone to Sql Injection. http://xkcd.com/327/ Please use parameterized queries or stored procedures.

Comment: This is for personal use and the program is protected by numerous passwords. SQL Injection's are not a concern, thanks anyway.

Comment: SQL injection should **always** be a concern. Just as you always put on your seatbelt in the car, even for the shortest of trips, you should always do the right thing when it comes to accessing your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with this code:

```
stcon = "CONNECTION STRING"
        con = New SqlConnection(stcon)

        da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT U_G_Studio FROM PersonsA WHERE Members_ID =" & SendFromID.Text, con)
        Dim dt = New DataTable

        da.Fill(dt)

            CurrentPoints.Text = dt.Rows(0)("U_G_Studio").ToString()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) automatically takes care of disposing resources. Also parameterize your query to avoid sql injection attacks.

```
stcon = "CONNECTION STRING;"
Dim strUGStudio As String

Dim sql As String = _
"SELECT U_G_Studio FROM PersonsA WHERE Members_ID = @MemberId"

Using conn As New SqlConnection(stcon)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MemberId", SendFromID.Text)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        strUGStudio = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try 
End Using 

Return strUGStudio
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT U_G_Studio FROM PersonsA WHERE Members_ID = @id")
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", SendFromID.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to then do ExecuteScalar(), assign that to a variable, and display it in the text box.

Answer (score 0):

If the Members Id is integer then you should try

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT U_G_Studio FROM PersonsA WHERE Members_ID =" &  SendFromID.Text , con)
```